# Difference between '*[]int' vs '[]*int'

Tags: go

What's the difference between  `*[]int` and `[]*int` in Go, can someone gives me an in-depth explanation of the same?

Comment: The first is a pointer to a slice of int.  The second is a slice of int pointers.

Comment: It's the same difference like in C (albeit C uses a different syntax).

Answer (score 2):

- `*[]int`: Pointer to a slice of `int`
- `[]*int`: Slice of pointer to `int`

Sample Program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2, 3}

    // y is a pointer to a slice of int
    y := &x
    fmt.Printf("%T -> %v\n", y, y)

    // Every element in the slice z is a pointer
    // to an int.
    z := []*int{&x[0], &x[1], &x[2]}
    fmt.Printf("%T -> %v\n", z, z)
}
```

Output:

```
*[]int -> &[1 2 3]
[]*int -> [0xc0000aa000 0xc0000aa008 0xc0000aa010]
```